# Cannot Resolve Method getElementsByTagName

Tags: android, google-maps

i have been trying to draw a path between to given point in android. but im getting an error saying **cannot resolve method getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)** is there anything i can do get rid of this?

**im getting my error in these line**

nodeListStep = elementLeg.getElementsByTagName("step");

and

decodePolylines(elementStep.getElementsByTagName("points").item(0).getTextContent());

i tried doing this example 
http://mrbool.com/google-directions-api-tracing-routes-in-android/32001

this is my **RotaTask.java**

```
    public class RotaTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    private static final String TOAST_MSG = "Calculating";
    private static final String TOAST_ERR_MAJ = "Impossible to trace Itinerary";
    private Context context; private GoogleMap gMap;
    private String editFrom; private String editTo;
    private final ArrayList<LatLng> lstLatLng = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    public RotaTask(final Context context, final GoogleMap gMap, final String editFrom, final String editTo) {
        this.context = context;
        this.gMap= gMap;
        this.editFrom = editFrom;
        this.editTo = editTo;
    }

    /** * {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(context, TOAST_MSG, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /*** * {@inheritDoc} */

    @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?sensor=false&language=pt"); url.append("&origin="); url.append(editFrom.replace(' ', '+')); url.append("&destination=");
            url.append(editTo.replace(' ', '+'));
            final InputStream stream = new URL(url.toString()).openStream();
            final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilderFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
            final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            final Document document = documentBuilder.parse(stream);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            final String status = document.getElementsByTagName("status").item(0).getTextContent();

            if(!"OK".equals(status)) {
                return false;
            }

            final Element elementLeg = (Element) document.getElementsByTagName("leg").item(0);
            final NodeList nodeListStep;
            nodeListStep = elementLeg.getElementsByTagName("step");
            final int length = nodeListStep.getLength();

            for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
                final Node nodeStep = nodeListStep.item(i);

                if(nodeStep.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    final Element elementStep = (Element) nodeStep;
                    decodePolylines(elementStep.getElementByTagName("points").item(0).getTextContent());
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        catch(final Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private void decodePolylines(final String encodedPoints) {
        int index = 0;
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < encodedPoints.length()) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;

            do {
                b = encodedPoints.charAt(index++) - 63; result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift; shift += 5;
            }

            while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat; shift = 0; result = 0;
            do {
                b = encodedPoints.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5; } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng; lstLatLng.add(new LatLng((double)lat/1E5, (double)lng/1E5));
        }
    }

    /** * {@inheritDoc} */

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {

        if(!result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, TOAST_ERR_MAJ, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        else {
            final PolylineOptions polylines = new PolylineOptions();
            polylines.color(Color.BLUE);

            for(final LatLng latLng : lstLatLng) {
                polylines.add(latLng);
            }

            final MarkerOptions markerA = new MarkerOptions();

            markerA.position(lstLatLng.get(0));
            markerA.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            final MarkerOptions markerB = new MarkerOptions();
            markerB.position(lstLatLng.get(lstLatLng.size()-1));
            markerB.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lstLatLng.get(0), 10)); gMap.addMarker(markerA);
            gMap.addPolyline(polylines); gMap.addMarker(markerB);
        }
    }




}
```

this is **acitiy_main.xml**

```
<
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:text="From"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFrom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="3" android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:text="To"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnGo"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="Go" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show us what you have done please..

Comment: @Lal im trying to post my code here still struggling to do

Comment: Lal's answer is correct. You should accept it

Comment: @metalurgus this is the code

Comment: @KalpaDilshan you still have a typo here:    if(nodeStep.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    final Element elementStep = (Element) nodeStep;
                    decodePolylines(elementStep.get**ElementByTag**Name("points").item(0).getTextContent());
                }

Comment: i made it but still it says the same :(

Comment: @metalurgus here is the resource i followed http://mrbool.com/google-directions-api-tracing-routes-in-android/32001 but still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

**You have a typo here**

it should be,

```
getElementsByTagName()
```

and not

```
getElementByTagName()
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

> The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live
>   HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

Comment: i have been trying to do this http://mrbool.com/google-directions-api-tracing-routes-in-android/32001 in android studio. and im getting an error like this

Comment: Ok and did you make the correction as i said in my answer?

Comment: it was typing mistake Lal im sorry. in my code its getElementsByTagName()

Comment: Oh.. Now actually what's the error? Could you please post the logcat.

Comment: i couldn't run it ! before run it theres the error in the code saying cannot resolve method getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)

Comment: Sure.. But right now, I'm from my mobile. Will update you soon from my PC.

Comment: is there anyway i can contact you?  to get an answer for this?  this is kind of urgent  :) i have been trying to finish this from 5 days

Comment: Lal thank you man! if u need more to know here is the resource i followed
http://mrbool.com/google-directions-api-tracing-routes-in-android/32001

Comment: from   nodeListStep = elementLeg.getElementsByTagName("step");

and 
decodePolylines(elementStep.getElementByTagName("points").item(0).getTextContent());

Comment: Notice elementStep. **getElementByTagName("points")** .item(0).getTextContent‌​()..replace it as `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: if still the same error, Since there is no error in the previous lines where you have used `getElementsByTagName `,  i think, the tutorial you are using is not correct..try an other one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the necro, BUT, I just bumped into this issue while helping someone, and hope that if someone else finds it this will be helpful in the future.

Make sure you import the right Element class(from org.w3c.dom).[image]

It's such a simple issue and it's been unsolved for so long.